# Unable to add Java service reference to WCF client

Tags: wcf

I am uanble to add the below Java service reference in WCF Client
https://filetransfer.nordea.com/services/CorporateFileService

getting below error .

There was an error downloading 'https://filetransfer.nordea.com/services/CorporateFileService/$metadata'. The request failed with the error:

I opened the port 8000. still getting same issue.

Please let me know what is the issue.

Thanks
Jaya

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a WCF service normally expose a file called a WSDL(Web Services Description Language) - this file explains the methods that you will use with the service

https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/NOTE-wsdl-20010315

Normally an endpoint needs to be created and be accessible for ypu to be able to view the service, what I would suggest is that if WCF doesnt seem to be doing that for you, try adding the service as a webservice Reference in your C#/Java project.

https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/infinitydevguide/Subsystems/infGC-developer-help/Content/AddingWebReference.htm